# How can I add an image thumbnail to my listview automatically?

Tags: android, listview, thumbnails

My goal is to add a thumbnail image in each of the listview entries. When the program opens, it downloads the images to the sd card. How can I make it so that the first entry on the listview has the thumbnail of image1 and the second entry automatically gets thumbnail image2, etc etc.  I need this to be programmatically done since I have a menu of 1200+ options all with corresonding images. I have modified the R.layout.itemlayout file so that it has an imageview, I'm just not sure how to programmatically change the source of the imageview based on its position within the listview. Thanks in advance!

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Chapter0Menu extends ListActivity {
private static final String TAG = null;
public static String url;
public static String[] fileArray;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] chapter0Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapter0);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Chapter0Menu.this, R.layout.itemlayout, chapter0Array));
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you accept a few answers to your MANY questions, someone might be a little more inclined to help you. ;O)

Comment: sorry, didn't realize you could accept answers...will do!  thanks for letting me know, i'm pretty new to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to use the customListAdapter to done this List view for display the multiple Images and what ever you want.
See [this example](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx). in this example there are multiple textview. Here instead of the text view you can take the Image view to show the Image you want.
Hope it will help you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just shared my personal class to dowload images in a download queue to you sd-card. Please try to use it and tell me if it's what you're looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/imagemanager/